# Regular Expression credit card match using Trailing Number

Tags: regex, credit-card

I'm attempting to do positive/negative (only) matching of credit cards.  I need to identify whether or not there are additional trailing numbers (only).

I can have any arbitrary string, but only trigger a match if there are more than 2 consecutive numbers (with any whitespace) AFTER the number.

I've worked through refining this a ton based on our needs, bit I did it gradually over a few months.  You can ignore much of the complexity (it's just doing precise digit matching for credit cards).  I'm just trying to deal with additional trailing numbers.  Regex I am currently using is here:

```
\b(?<!\d.)(3[47]\d{2}([ -]?)(?!(\d)\3{5}|123456|234567|345678|5454545)\d{6}\2(?!(\d)\4{4})\d{5}|((4\d|5[1-5]|65)\d{2}|6011)([ -]?)(?!(\d)\8{3}|1234|3456|5678)\d{4}\7(?!(\d)\9{3})\d{4}\7\d{4})(\b|\s)
```

The following matches already successfully match:

```
some 4270446050075048
4270-4460-5007-5048
this:4270 4460 5007 5048.
4270 4460 5007 5048 4/20
4270 4460 5007 5048 what
4270 4460 5007 5048
```

The following successfully do NOT match:

```
42704460500750a8
4270
4270 4460 5007 504
42811293test123
```

However, this one is getting me.  There are a bunch of files with this type of long numeric pattern that keep getting caught.  I would like to update the included regex to eliminate a valid match if and only if it is followed by at least 3 more numbers, such as in the following examples:

```
4270 4460 5007 5048 1234 5083 5095 5179 5157 5219 5187 5095  
4270 4460 5007 5048 123123115132124151231
4270 4460 5007 5048123
42704460500750481234
```

But the following SHOULD CONTINUE to generate a match (due to Expiry date notation):

```
4270 4460 5007 5048 12
```

I have tried the following as a negative lookahead, but I may be misunderstanding what I need to do:

```
 (?![\d][^\d][^\d])
```

That resulted in some weird changes to matches, which I didn't quite get (only matched strings with no trailing space, or with one trailing space, but any number of digits).  I built this in sections and I am unsure how multiple lookaside functions interplay with each other, which may be part of the issue.

If you are interested in trying it out, a pre-built testbed for this is here:

https://regex101.com/r/oE1rZ1/2

Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow.  Please be more specific.  What pattern are you using.  What is it matching (or not matching)?  What do you expect it to match?

Comment: If you need a match to fail based on something after it, you need to use negative lookahead. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I updated it to hopefully add clarity

Comment: @EricM: Please check [`\b(?<!\d.)(3[47]\d{2}([ -]?)(?!(\d)\3{5}|123456|234567|345678|5454545)\d{6}\2(?!(\d)\4{4})\d{5}|((4\d|5[1-5]|65)\d{2}|6011)([ -]?)(?!(\d)\8{3}|1234|3456|5678)\d{4}\7(?!(\d)\9{3})\d{4}\7\d{4,5})\b(?![ ]+\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/bS6eA8/1). Mind that in the beginning, `\b(?<!\d.)` is checking if there is a digit and a non-word character after it, perhaps, you wanted [`\b(?<!\d[ ])`](https://regex101.com/r/bS6eA8/2)?

Comment: The beginning is a lookbehind to validate if there is a number prior to it.  Thanks for the feedback, however.  I figured out the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this for 4 hours, realized what I was missing.

The string I needed was:

```
(?!.\d\d)
```

The final credit card matching string (the best one I've ever seen) is this:

```
\b(?<!\d.)(3[47]\d{2}([ -]?)(?!(\d)\3{5}|123456|234567|345678|424242|545454|11111)\d{6}\2(?!(\d)\4{4})\d{5}|((4\d|5[1-5]|65)\d{2}|6011)([ -]?)(?!(\d)\8{3}|4242|5454|1234|3456|5678|2345|4567|1111)\d{4}\7(?!(\d)\9{3})\d{4}\7\d{4})(\b|\s)(?!.\d\d)
```

It errs a tiny bit on the side of false negatives in order to exclude most "testing" and "sample" numbers such as 4242 4242 4242 42424 and 5454 5454 5454 5454 or 1234 5678 9012 3456 or 4111 1111 1111 1111, 4123 4567 8901 1111 etc.

Thanks for the inspiration, folks.  :-)

A detailed test suite for this particular regex is located at this link:

https://regex101.com/r/rW1fF3/1